# Docker compose with Erpnext not working on Compute Engine

Tags: docker, nginx, traefik, erpnext

thanks for your time!
I'm trying to setup a frappe erpnext instance on a Google Compute Engine instance. I'm using the easy-install script provided on their website, which provides me with this docker compose:

```
name: frappe
services:
  backend:
    depends_on:
      configurator:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        required: true
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  configurator:
    command:
    - |
      ls -1 apps > sites/apps.txt; bench set-config -g db_host $$DB_HOST; bench set-config -gp db_port $$DB_PORT; bench set-config -g redis_cache "redis://$$REDIS_CACHE"; bench set-config -g redis_queue "redis://$$REDIS_QUEUE"; bench set-config -g redis_socketio "redis://$$REDIS_SOCKETIO"; bench set-config -gp socketio_port $$SOCKETIO_PORT;
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        required: true
      redis-cache:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
      redis-queue:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
      redis-socketio:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
    entrypoint:
    - bash
    - -c
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: "3306"
      REDIS_CACHE: redis-cache:6379
      REDIS_QUEUE: redis-queue:6379
      REDIS_SOCKETIO: redis-socketio:6379
      SOCKETIO_PORT: "9000"
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  db:
    command:
    - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
    - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    - --skip-character-set-client-handshake
    - --skip-innodb-read-only-compressed
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXX
    healthcheck:
      test:
      - CMD-SHELL
      - mysqladmin ping -h localhost --password=XXXX
      interval: 1s
      retries: 15
    image: mariadb:10.6
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: db-data
      target: /var/lib/mysql
      volume: {}
  frontend:
    command:
    - nginx-entrypoint.sh
    depends_on:
      backend:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
      websocket:
        condition: service_started
        required: true
    environment:
      BACKEND: backend:8000
      CLIENT_MAX_BODY_SIZE: 50m
      FRAPPE_SITE_NAME_HEADER: $$host
      PROXY_READ_TIMOUT: "120"
      SOCKETIO: websocket:9000
      UPSTREAM_REAL_IP_ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
      UPSTREAM_REAL_IP_HEADER: X-Forwarded-For
      UPSTREAM_REAL_IP_RECURSIVE: "off"
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.rule: Host(`site1.localhost`,`app.nexforce.ai`)
      traefik.http.routers.frontend-http.tls.certresolver: main-resolver
      traefik.http.services.frontend.loadbalancer.server.port: "8080"
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  proxy:
    command:
    - --providers.docker=true
    - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
    - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=https
    - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
    - --certificatesResolvers.main-resolver.acme.httpChallenge=true
    - --certificatesResolvers.main-resolver.acme.httpChallenge.entrypoint=web
    - --certificatesResolvers.main-resolver.acme.email=xxx@xxx.co
    - --certificatesResolvers.main-resolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
    image: traefik:2.5
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
    - mode: ingress
      target: 80
      published: "80"
      protocol: tcp
    - mode: ingress
      target: 443
      published: "443"
      protocol: tcp
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: cert-data
      target: /letsencrypt
      volume: {}
    - type: bind
      source: /var/run/docker.sock
      target: /var/run/docker.sock
      read_only: true
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
  queue-default:
    command:
    - bench
    - worker
    - --queue
    - default
    depends_on:
      configurator:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        required: true
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  queue-long:
    command:
    - bench
    - worker
    - --queue
    - long
    depends_on:
      configurator:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        required: true
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  queue-short:
    command:
    - bench
    - worker
    - --queue
    - short
    depends_on:
      configurator:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        required: true
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  redis-cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: redis-cache-data
      target: /data
      volume: {}
  redis-queue:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: redis-queue-data
      target: /data
      volume: {}
  redis-socketio:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: redis-socketio-data
      target: /data
      volume: {}
  scheduler:
    command:
    - bench
    - schedule
    depends_on:
      configurator:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        required: true
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
  websocket:
    command:
    - node
    - /home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/socketio.js
    depends_on:
      configurator:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
        required: true
    image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: volume
      source: sites
      target: /home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
      volume: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: frappe_default
volumes:
  cert-data:
    name: frappe_cert-data
  db-data:
    name: frappe_db-data
  redis-cache-data:
    name: frappe_redis-cache-data
  redis-queue-data:
    name: frappe_redis-queue-data
  redis-socketio-data:
    name: frappe_redis-socketio-data
  sites:
    name: frappe_sites
x-backend-defaults:
  depends_on:
    configurator:
      condition: service_completed_successfully
  image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
  volumes:
  - sites:/home/frappe/frappe-bench/sites
x-customizable-image:
  image: frappe/erpnext:v14.34.3
x-depends-on-configurator:
  depends_on:
    configurator:
      condition: service_completed_successfully
```

The docker log shows me:

```
frappe-queue-short-1  | 2023-08-15 19:53:13,861 Worker rq:worker:f0f55875e9a949e485219f7e26332148.8bf8dec2e88f.1.home-frappe-frappe-bench:short: started, version 1.11.1
frappe-queue-short-1  | 2023-08-15 19:53:13,861 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:f0f55875e9a949e485219f7e26332148.8bf8dec2e88f.1.home-frappe-frappe-bench:short
frappe-queue-short-1  | 2023-08-15 19:53:13,863 *** Listening on home-frappe-frappe-bench:short...
frappe-queue-short-1  | 2023-08-15 19:53:13,864 Cleaning registries for queue: home-frappe-frappe-bench:short
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.065 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.065 # Redis version=6.2.13, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.065 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.075 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.076 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.076 # Server initialized
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.076 * Ready to accept connections
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:40:29.862 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:40:29.863 * Background saving started by pid 15
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 15:C 15 Aug 2023 20:40:29.871 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 15:C 15 Aug 2023 20:40:29.871 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:40:29.963 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 21:40:30.078 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-queue-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 21:40:30.078 * Background saving started by pid 16
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 16:C 15 Aug 2023 21:40:30.083 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 16:C 15 Aug 2023 21:40:30.083 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 23:40:32.073 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
frappe-queue-long-1   | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,401 Worker rq:worker:79f44bd81bcc4580bec7d6345ba1f153.1eb2d3c42da5.1.home-frappe-frappe-bench:long: started, version 1.11.1
frappe-queue-long-1      | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,402 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:79f44bd81bcc4580bec7d6345ba1f153.1eb2d3c42da5.1.home-frappe-frappe-bench:long
frappe-queue-long-1      | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,404 *** Listening on home-frappe-frappe-bench:long...
frappe-queue-long-1      | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,413 Cleaning registries for queue: home-frappe-frappe-bench:long
frappe-queue-long-1      | 2023-08-15 20:20:15,077 Cleaning registries for queue: home-frappe-frappe-bench:long
frappe-queue-long-1      | 2023-08-15 20:47:15,347 Cleaning registries for queue:
frappe-queue-long-1      | 2023-08-16 13:53:23,017 Cleaning registries for queue: home-frappe-frappe-bench:long
frappe-proxy-1        | time="2023-08-15T19:52:45Z" level=info msg="Configuration loaded from flags."
frappe-proxy-1           | time="2023-08-15T19:53:25Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"site1.localhost,app.nexforce.ai\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [site1.localhost app.nexforce.ai]: acme: error: 400 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:rejectedIdentifier :: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for \"site1.localhost\": Domain name does not end with a valid public suffix (TLD)" rule="Host(`site1.localhost`,`app.nexforce.ai`)" routerName=frontend-http@docker providerName=main-resolver.acme
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.538 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.538 # Redis version=6.2.13, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.538 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.539 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.539 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.539 # Server initialized
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:44.540 * Ready to accept connections
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:57:45.238 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:57:45.240 * Background saving started by pid 15
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 15:C 15 Aug 2023 19:57:45.249 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 15:C 15 Aug 2023 19:57:45.250 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:57:45.488 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:02:46.238 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:02:46.238 * Background saving started by pid 16
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 16:C 15 Aug 2023 20:02:46.257 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 16:C 15 Aug 2023 20:02:46.258 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:02:46.488 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:07:47.239 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:07:47.242 * Background saving started by pid 17
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 17:C 15 Aug 2023 20:07:47.261 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 17:C 15 Aug 2023 20:07:47.262 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:07:47.488 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:12:48.238 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:12:48.238 * Background saving started by pid 18
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 18:C 15 Aug 2023 20:12:48.255 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 18:C 15 Aug 2023 20:12:48.257 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:12:48.488 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:17:49.238 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:17:49.238 * Background saving started by pid 19
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 19:C 15 Aug 2023 20:17:49.252 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 19:C 15 Aug 2023 20:17:49.253 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:17:49.488 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:22:50.075 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:22:50.075 * Background saving started by pid 20
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 20:C 15 Aug 2023 20:22:50.090 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 20:C 15 Aug 2023 20:22:50.091 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-cache-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 20:22:50.176 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.105 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.105 # Redis version=6.2.13, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:C 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.105 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.106 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.107 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.107 # Server initialized
frappe-redis-socketio-1  | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 19:52:45.107 * Ready to accept connections
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 15 Aug 2023 23:40:32.074 * Background saving started by pid 18
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 16 Aug 2023 06:40:39.031 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 16 Aug 2023 06:40:39.032 * Background saving started by pid 25
frappe-queue-default-1   | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,564 Worker rq:worker:1a4ef948f4fb443f9238ecd6716fdfbc.ef6ffef6fd5a.1.home-frappe-frappe-bench:default: started, version 1.11.1
frappe-queue-default-1   | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,565 Subscribing to channel rq:pubsub:1a4ef948f4fb443f9238ecd6716fdfbc.ef6ffef6fd5a.1.home-frappe-frappe-bench:default
frappe-queue-default-1   | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,567 *** Listening on home-frappe-frappe-bench:default...
frappe-queue-default-1   | 2023-08-15 19:53:14,568 Cleaning registries for queue: 
frappe-queue-default-1   | 2023-08-16 13:26:22,778 Cleaning registries for queue: home-frappe-frappe-bench:default
frappe-queue-default-1   | 2023-08-16 13:53:22,916 Cleaning registries for queue: home-frappe-frappe-bench:default
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 25:C 16 Aug 2023 06:40:39.037 * DB saved on disk
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 25:C 16 Aug 2023 06:40:39.037 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 16 Aug 2023 06:40:39.132 * Background saving terminated with success
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 16 Aug 2023 07:40:40.044 * 1 changes in 3600 seconds. Saving...
frappe-redis-queue-1     | 1:M 16 Aug 2023 07:40:40.045 * Background saving started by pid 26
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2004 started.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2004 started.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:45+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-backend-1         | [2023-08-15 19:53:15 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
frappe-backend-1         | [2023-08-15 19:53:15 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
frappe-backend-1         | [2023-08-15 19:53:15 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
frappe-backend-1         | [2023-08-15 19:53:15 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17
frappe-backend-1         | [2023-08-15 19:53:15 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
frappe-frontend-1        | PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT defaulting to 120
frappe-db-1              | databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
frappe-db-1              | strongly recommended for production servers.
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
frappe-db-1              | https://mariadb.org/get-involved/
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.14-MariaDB-1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2004 source revision c93754d45e5d9379e3e23d7ada1d5f21d2711f66 as process 111
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.14 started; log sequence number 42120; transaction id 14
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@f5aac9708dd6' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@f5aac9708dd6' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:47 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
frappe-db-1              | Version: '10.6.14-MariaDB-1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2004'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:48 3 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:49 6 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:50 7 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:51 8 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 230815 19:52:52
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 42132; transaction id 15
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB init process done. Ready for start up.
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.14-MariaDB-1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2004 source revision c93754d45e5d9379e3e23d7ada1d5f21d2711f66 as process 1
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.14 started; log sequence number 42132; transaction id 14
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230815 19:52:53
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:52:53 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
frappe-db-1              | Version: '10.6.14-MariaDB-1:10.6.14+maria~ubu2004'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 19:53:16 22 [Warning] Aborted connection 22 to db: '_e1ef3e0c4bdfa786' user: '_e1ef3e0c4bdfa786' host: '172.20.0.7' (Got an error reading communication packets)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 20:05:08 24 [Warning] Aborted connection 24 to db: '_e1ef3e0c4bdfa786' user: '_e1ef3e0c4bdfa786' host: '172.20.0.7' (Got an error reading communication packets)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 20:05:21 537 [Warning] Aborted connection 537 to db: '_1e2a3850be61823a' user: '_1e2a3850be61823a' host: '172.20.0.7' (Got an error reading communication packets)
frappe-db-1              | 2023-08-15 20:19:03 542 [Warning] Aborted connection 542 to db: '_1e2a3850be61823a' user: '_1e2a3850be61823a' host: '172.20.0.7' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Bottom line is, it seems everything is running smoothly, but I can't get to make it work. I can't access the website, nothing ever shows up (even trying ip:8080 or ip:9000) and so on.

My compute engine has the HTTP traffic enable for port 80:

```
default-allow-http      Ingress firewall rule   Global  1000    
Tags: http-server
IPv4 ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
—
tcp:80
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!